# Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, out-parameters, ref-parameters

Take the following:

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

class C
{
    C()
    {
        var b = new B();
        Foo(b);
        Foo2(ref b); // <= compile-time error: 
                     // "The 'ref' argument doesn't match the parameter type"
    }

    void Foo(A a) {}

    void Foo2(ref A a) {}  
}
```

Why does the above compile-time error occur? This happens with both `ref` and `out` arguments.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

=============

UPDATE: I used this answer as the basis for this blog entry:

[Why do ref and out parameters not allow type variation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx)

See the blog page for more commentary on this issue.  Thanks for the great question.

=============

Let's suppose you have classes `Animal`, `Mammal`, `Reptile`, `Giraffe`, `Turtle` and `Tiger`, with the obvious subclassing relationships.

Now suppose you have a method `void M(ref Mammal m)`.  `M` can both read and write `m`.

---

> Can you pass a variable of type `Animal` to `M`?

No. That variable could contain a `Turtle`, but `M` will assume that it contains only Mammals. A `Turtle` is not a `Mammal`.

**Conclusion 1**: `ref` parameters cannot be made "bigger". (There are more animals than mammals, so the variable is getting "bigger" because it can contain more things.)

---

> Can you pass a variable of type `Giraffe` to `M`?

No. `M` can write to `m`, and `M` might want to write a `Tiger` into `m`.  Now you've put a `Tiger` into a variable which is actually of type `Giraffe`.

**Conclusion 2**: `ref` parameters cannot be made "smaller".

---

Now consider `N(out Mammal n)`.

> Can you pass a variable of type `Giraffe` to `N`?

No. `N` can write to `n`, and `N` might want to write a `Tiger`.

**Conclusion 3**: `out` parameters cannot be made "smaller".

---

> Can you pass a variable of type `Animal` to `N`?

Hmm.

Well, why not?  `N` cannot read from `n`, it can only write to it, right?  You write a `Tiger` to a variable of type `Animal` and you're all set, right?

Wrong. The rule is not "`N` can only write to `n`".

The rules are, briefly:

1) `N` has to write to `n` before `N` returns normally. (If `N` throws, all bets are off.)

2) `N` has to write something to `n` before it reads something from `n`.

That permits this sequence of events:

- Declare a field `x` of type `Animal`.
- Pass `x` as an `out` parameter to `N`.
- `N` writes a `Tiger` into `n`, which is an alias for `x`.
- On another thread, someone writes a `Turtle` into `x`.
- `N` attempts to read the contents of `n`, and discovers a `Turtle` in what it thinks is a variable of type `Mammal`.

Clearly we want to make that illegal.

**Conclusion 4**: `out` parameters cannot be made "larger".

---

*Final conclusion*: **Neither `ref` nor `out` parameters may vary their types. To do otherwise is to break verifiable type safety.**

If these issues in basic type theory interest you, consider reading [my series on how covariance and contravariance work in C# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx).

Comment: +1. Great explanation using real-world class examples that clearly demonstrate the issues (i.e. - explaining with A, B and C makes it harder to demonstrate why it doesn't work).

Comment: I feel humbled reading this thought process. I think I better get back to the books!

Comment: In this case, we really cant use Abstract class variable as arguments and pass on its derived class object!!

Comment: Still, why `out` parameters cannot be made "larger"? Sequence you've described can be applied to any variable, not only `out` parameter variable. And also the reader needs to cast the argument value to `Mammal` before he attempts to access it as `Mammal` and of course it can fail if he is not considerate

Comment: One case not covered here is when you use the implicit operator on a type. For example, I declare `MyDouble` with the implicit operator so the compiler *knows* how to make the conversion from `System.Double` to `MyDouble`. But still, I can't call `double.TryParse("0.1", out MyDouble result)` even though the assignment `MyDouble result2 = result;` is legal on the very next line.

Answer (score 31):

Because in both cases you must be able to assign value to ref/out parameter.

If you try to pass b into Foo2 method as reference, and in Foo2 you try to assing a = new A(), this would be invalid.
Same reason you can't write:

```
B b = new A();
```

Comment: +1 Straight to the point and explains perfectly well the reason.

Answer (score 10):

You're struggling with the classic OOP problem of **covariance** (and contravariance), see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)): much as this fact may defy intuitive expectations, it's mathematically impossible to allow substitution of derived classes in lieu of base ones for mutable (assignable) arguments (and also containers whose items are assignable, for just the same reason) while still respecting [Liskov's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Why that is so is sketched in the existing answers, and explored more deeply in these wiki articles and links therefrom.

OOP languages that appear to do so while remaining traditionally statically typesafe are "cheating" (inserting hidden dynamic type checks, or requiring compile-time examination of ALL sources to check); the fundamental choice is: either give up on this covariance and accept practitioners' puzzlement (as C# does here), or move to a dynamic typing approach (as the very first OOP language, Smalltalk, did), or move to immutable (single-assignment) data, like functional languages do (under immutability, you can support covariance, and also avoid other related puzzles such as the fact that you cannot have Square subclass Rectangle in a mutable-data world).

Answer (score 5):

Consider:

```
class C : A {}
class B : A {}

void Foo2(ref A a) { a = new C(); } 

B b = null;
Foo2(ref b);
```

It would violate type-safety

Comment: It's more the unclear inferred type of "b" due to the var that's the problem there.

Comment: I guess on line 6 you meant => B b = null;

Comment: @amiralles - yes, that `var` was totally wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

While the other responses have succinctly explained the reasoning behind this behavior, I think it's worth mentioning that if you really need to do something of this nature you can accomplish similar functionality by making Foo2 into a generic method, as such:

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

class C
{
    C()
    {
        var b = new B();
        Foo(b);
        Foo2(ref b); // <= no compile error!
    }

    void Foo(A a) {}

    void Foo2<AType> (ref AType a) where AType: A {}  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because giving `Foo2` a `ref B` would result in a malformed object because `Foo2` only knows how to fill `A` part of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the compiler telling you it would like you to explicitly cast the object so that it can be sure you know what your intentions are?

```
Foo2(ref (A)b)
```

Comment: Can't do that, "A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable"

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense from a safety perspective, but I would have preferred it if the compiler gave a warning instead of an error, since there are legitimate uses of polymoprhic objects passed by reference. e.g.

```
class Derp : interfaceX
{
   int somevalue=0; //specified that this class contains somevalue by interfaceX
   public Derp(int val)
    {
    somevalue = val;
    }

}


void Foo(ref object obj){
    int result = (interfaceX)obj.somevalue;
    //do stuff to result variable... in my case data access
    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType(), result);
}

main()
{
   Derp x = new Derp();
   Foo(ref Derp);
}
```

This won't compile, but would it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use practical examples for your types, you'll see it:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
Foo(ref connection);
```

And now you have your function that takes the *ancestor* (*i.e.* `Object`):

```
void Foo2(ref Object connection) { }
```

What can possibly be wrong with that?

```
void Foo2(ref Object connection)
{
   connection = new Bitmap();
}
```

You just managed to assign a `Bitmap` to your `SqlConnection`.

That's no good.

---

Try again with others:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
Foo2(ref conn);

void Foo2(ref DbConnection connection)
{
    conn = new OracleConnection();
}
```

You stuffed an [`OracleConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) over-top of your `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my function accepted an object and I couldn't send in anything so I simply did

```
object bla = myVar;
Foo(ref bla);
```

And that works

My Foo is in VB.NET and it checks for type inside and does a lot of logic

I apologize if my answer is duplicate but others were too long