# cannot convert from 'out T' to 'out Component'

Tags: c#

here is some C# code that does not compile, giving the following message :

***cannot convert from 'out T' to 'out Component'***

```
    public void Get<T>(out T c) where T : Component
    {
        m_components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out c);
    }
```

Here is code that does compile :

```
    public void Get<T>(out T c) where T : Component
    {
        Component temp;
        m_components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out temp);
        c = (T)temp;
    }
```

I wonder why the first code is not valid since the ***"where T : Component"*** explicitly states that T is of type Component.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to make "Get<T>" a generic method if T is defined to be of type Component?
May be you are haven;t mentioned the exact scenario here.

Comment: *twiddles thumbs waiting for Mr. Skeet to enlighten us on this intriguing issue*

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302

Comment: @Amby : m_components is a Dictionary of Components Dictionary<Type, Components>. It may contains any derivated object based on the abstract class Component. The usage is for example :
PhysicComponent physicComponent;
ModelComponent modelComponent;
entity.Get<PhysicComponent>(out physicComponent);
entity.Get<ModelComponent>(out modelComponent);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot at a more elaborate version of @Rex's answer and slightly corrected version of @Courtney's signature in that the type is Component, not object. Courtney's answer is basically right, just the types are a bit off.

```
bool TryGetValue(Type key, out Component result)
{
       if (this.Contains(key))
       {
           result = this[key]; // the type of result is Component!
           return true;
       }

      return false;
}
```

by passing T as the object type, you are trying to *implicitly* cast the base type Component to a subtype T. That is why your second example works. TryGetValue doesn't know about your Generic type T, it thinks everything in m_Components is a Component object.

This is a pretty common thing to get stuck thinking backwards. Because it's a parameter, not the return type, you get sucked into thinking it should work like any other parameter. However, because it's an **out**, it actually is better thought of as a return type for this purpose... it is going to try to assign the value of it's internal work to the parameter you provide.

Answer (score 13):

It's because `out` parameter types cannot be [covariant/contravariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). **The type of the variable must exactly match the parameter type.**

See:

```
class Super { }
class Sub : Super { }

void Test(out Super s)
{
    s = new Super();
}

void Main()
{
    Sub mySub = new Sub();
    Test(out mySub); //doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the **out** and it does not relate to Generics

we can produce the same error as follows

```
class A
{
}

void fn(out object x)
{
 x= new object();
}
void main()
{
 A x;
fn(out x); //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out:

What if you have the following:

```
 public class BaseClass { ... }
 public class SubClass : BaseClass { ... }
```

then I have the code:

```
 Dictionary<int, BaseClass> comps;

 public void Get<T>(int num, out T c) where T : BaseClass
 {
     comps.TryGetValue(num, out c);
 }
```

And I try to call it as thus:

```
 SubClass sub;
 Get<SubClass>(1, out sub);
```

Sub assume that the `BaseClass` with a key of 1 was actually a `BaseClass` and not a `SubClass`.  Or Perhaps it is `OtherSubClass` where `OtherSubClass : BaseClass`

Answer (score -2):

This is interesting.

I don't have an answer, but it's worth noting (to me, anyway), that the following works:

```
    public void M<T> (out T c) where T : Test
    {
        // Test m;
        // A(out m);
        // c = (T) m;

        A(out c);
    }

    public void A<T> (out T t) where T : Test
    {
        t = null;
    }
```

-- Edit:

(It's interesting because even if it's `out object t` it's still not convertible between `out T` and `out object`)