# method with ref object parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have to call a method that has this signature:

```
int MethodName(ref object vIndexKey)
```

If i try to call it with

```
String c = "690";

MethodName(ref (object) c);
```

It doesn't work.

How can i do?

thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
String c = "690"; 
object o = (object) c;
MethodName(ref o);
```

The reason is that the parameter must be assignable by the function. The function could do something like this:

```
o = new List<int>();
```

Which is not possible if the underlying type is a string that has been casted to an object during the method call, because the target of the assignment would still be a string and not an object.

Answer (score 2):

When a method has a ref parameter, the argument type has to match the parameter type exactly. Suppose `MethodName` were implemented like this:

```
public void MethodName(ref object x)
{
    x = new object();
}
```

What would you expect to happen if you were able to call it with just `ref c`? It would be trying to write a reference to a plain `System.Object` into a variable of type `System.String`, thus breaking type safety.

So, you need to have a variable of type `object`. You can do that as shown in klausbyskov's answer, but be aware that the value *won't* then be copied back to the original variable. You can do this with a cast, but be aware that it may fail:

```
string c = "690";
object o = c;
MethodName(ref o);
// This will fail if `MethodName` has set the parameter value to a non-null
// non-string reference
c = (string) o;
```

Here's the relevant bit of the C# 3.0 spec, section 10.6.1.2 (emphasis mine):

> When a formal parameter is a reference
>   parameter, the corresponding argument
>   in a method invocation must consist of
>   the keyword ref followed by a
>   variable-reference (§5.3.3) **of the
>   same type as the formal parameter**. A
>   variable must be definitely assigned
>   before it can be passed as a reference
>   parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Does

```
MethodName(ref c);
```

not work?

Comment: No, for "ref" parameters the argument needs to be of exactly the same type.