# Problem with string as reference parameter when method takes Object C#

Tags: c#, object, reference, immutability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# : Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism)

I can't seem to understand why the following does not work in C#:

```
public static void Swap(ref Object a, ref Object b) {
    Object t = b;
    b = a;
    a = t;
}

//Calls
String fname = "Ford";
Strinf lname = "James";
Swap(ref lname, ref fname);
```

Is this because String already references to a char array, its immutable?

Comment: You have to say *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: this won't compile as is, and it's not just the typo

Comment: This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=VS.100).aspx) has an example function almost exactly the same, except it uses generics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a duplicate of

[Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302)

See that answer for why it doesn't work.

To make it work, you could make a generic method:

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) 
{
    T t = b;     
    b = a;     
    a = t; 
}
```

And now all the types check out.

Answer (score 3):

I once again have to link to a blog post by Eric Lippert (second time today!) on this very topic:

[Why do ref and out parameters not allow type variation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx)

Basically allowing this conversion would break type safety since you could *change* the object reference to hold another type that doesn't match whatever type the caller passed in.

> Neither ref nor out parameters may
>   vary in type at the call site. To do
>   otherwise is to break verifiable type
>   safety.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be able to compile, and thankfully so. Imagine you put an integer into object a or b, in the swap method. That wouldn't be possible at all, because the actual reference is to an object of type string.

You might pull this kind of behavior off in a dynamically typed scripting language like JavaScript or PHP, because everything is just a 'var' anyway. But in a statically typed language like C#, this is impossible.

Comment: In other words, `ref` parameters are *invariant* (i.e. you must use the exact same type). This is because they must be both *contravariant* (as normal parameters are) and *covariant* (as return types are). If you change `fname` and `lname` to have type `Object` this will work fine. You can read more on Eric Lippert's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx