# Conversion with out parameter type

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code:

```
DateTime? toDate = null;
DateTime.TryParseExact(toDateTextBox.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out toDate);
```

> Error: cannot convert from 'out System.DateTime?' to 'out System.DateTime'

I wonder why it is not possible to pass a convert `DateTime?` to `DateTime`, in spite of it is actually a conversion from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `out` and `ref` parameter the variable type **must match** the parameter type.

The main reason is to ensure type-safety, look at this example to have an idea:

```
public static void Do(out object value)
{
   value = new Foo();
} 


string myStr;
Do(out myStr); // OMG I'm setting Foo inside a string !!
```

Comment: I've just found an Eric Lippert's [blog entry dealing with this argument](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx) and it points also to a [really good question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302), then I will propose to close this question as duplicate :)

Answer (score 3):

An out param requires the exact same data type.  What is getting passed is a reference to the variable and that reference is getting updated with the value.  Since DateTime and DateTime? are actually two different types (regardless of the ability to convert between them) the call fails.

Comment: Why `regardless of the ability to convert between them` in `out` type and not in `in` type ?

Comment: Because the out param needs some place to store the DateTime object.  It can't store it in the DateTime? variable because they aren't the same type.  C# could probably do some magic under the covers to make it work, but that's probably very low on the list of priorities.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no implicit conversion exists between [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) to `DateTime`. (`DateTime?` is actually syntactic sugar for `Nullable<DateTime>`).

Nullable structure's Value Property is actually has the value of the valuetype.

Comment: It is `out` type. that means the conversion should from `DateTime?` to `DateTime` which is OK in C#.

Comment: Nope DateTime? instance's `.Value` property is convertible to `DateTime`.

Comment: @Jack just tried `DateTime?` to `DateTime` and it is not implicit, only explicit.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth: Thanks, I know that but I mean in `out` type it is actually `DateTime` to `DateTime?`

Answer (score 0):

cannot convert from **System.DateTime?** to **System.DateTime**
because this out parameter needs not nullable datetime type variable. but you are sending nullable datetime parameter to it.