# Passing by 'ref' - c#

Tags: c#, ref

Much to my dismay, the follow code wont compile.

It will however compile if I remove the `ref` keyword.

```
class xyz
{
    static void foo(ref object aaa)
    {
    }

    static void bar()
    {
        string bbb="";
        foo(ref bbb);
        //foo(ref (object)bbb); also doesnt work
    }
}
```

1. Can anyone explain this? Im guessing
   it has something to do with ref's
   being very strict with derived
   classes.
2. Is there any way I can pass an
       object of type string to `foo(ref
       object varname)`?

Comment: Note; if you are only passing the string *in*, you don't need `ref` here *anyway*; you ***only*** need `ref` here if `foo` is going to *reassign* `aaa`, ***and*** the caller needs to know about the reassignment.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to be an exact match, else `foo` could do:

```
aaa = 123;
```

which would be valid for `foo` (it will box the `int` to an `object`), but not for `bar` (where it is a `string`).

Two immediate options; firstly, use an intermediate variable and a type-check:

```
object tmp = bbb;
foo(ref tmp);
bbb = (string)tmp;
```

or alternatively, maybe try generics (`foo<T>(ref T aaa)`); or treat `bbb` as `object` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. Imagine the following:

```
static void Foo(ref object obj)
{
    obj = new SomeObject();
}

static void Bar()
{
    string s = "";
    Foo(ref s);
}
```

Foo would try to assign a `SomeObject` to a variable that's actually a `string`!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a varaible by reference, it has to match the type exactly.

You can call the method by creating another varaible with the correct type:

```
string bbb = "";
object o = bbb;
foo(ref o);
```

If you want the changed value back in the string variable, you have to check the type and cast it:

```
bbb = o as string;
```

---

Consider using a return value instead of the `ref` keyword, and just return the changed value:

```
static object foo(object aaa) {
```

Usage:

```
o = foo(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the exact same type. You can use advantage of `dynamic`

```
public static void foo(ref object a)
{
    a = "foo";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string bbb = "";
    dynamic a = bbb;        // or object
    foo(ref a);
    bbb = a;                // if it was object you need to cast to string

    Console.WriteLine(bbb); // foo
}
```