# int.TryParse out into an object array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array, and I want to check if a string is a number, and then put it in an object array as an int.

(For those of you asking why an object array, because I want to check for characters and other things too)

I have this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter parameters for the function with a space in between each parameter: "); String stringParameters = Console.ReadLine();
String[] parametersStringArray = stringParameters.Split(' ');
Object[] parametersArray = new Object[parametersStringArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < parametersStringArray.Length; i++)
{
    int.TryParse(parametersStringArray[i], out int.Parse(parametersArray[i]));
}
```

It doesn't compile and I am not familiar with the 'out' command, what's wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to put it into an `object` array...? As you are just putting `int` values in there......

Comment: parametersArray should be rather int array

Comment: why an object array? (you probably only need `out parametersArray[1]`)

Comment: The statement *"It doesn't compile"* without the compiler error is worthless.  What is the *exact* compiler error?

Comment: You should read this question and my answer to understand first, why you must give a *variable* as the parameter when passing `out` or `ref`, and second, why that variable must *exactly* match the parameter type.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-sharp-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism/1207302#1207302

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code

```
     Console.WriteLine("Enter parameters for the function with a space in between each parameter: "); String stringParameters = Console.ReadLine();
     String[] parametersStringArray = stringParameters.Split(' ');
     Object[] parametersArray = new Object[parametersStringArray.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < parametersStringArray.Length; i++)
     {
        int tmp;
        if (int.TryParse(parametersStringArray[i], out tmp))
           parametersArray[i] = tmp;

     }
```

Comment: Such a nice *Boxing* example.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **your target array has to be `int[]`, not `Object[]`**:

```
int[] parametersArray = new int[parametersStringArray.Length];
```

And your `TryParse` call is incorrect. Try following:

```
int.TryParse(parametersStringArray[i].ToString(), out parametersArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int res;
if (int.TryParse(parametersStringArray[i], out res)) {
    parametersArray[i] = res;
}
else {
Console.WriteLine("Not a number at index {0}", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
public static int? TryParse(string s)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

var res = new string[] { "1", "2", "a" }
    .Select(x => TryParse(x).GetValueOrDefault());
```